# Ubuntu 20.04 - Terminal Menu Bar - Alt H or Alt F not working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I am currently trying to use the Alt key to access the menu bar however it doesn't seem to be allowing for any input. For example, ALT h should bring up the help menu but it doesn't do anything.
It does show the underline in front of each word on the menu bar but that is as far as it goes.
Works perfectly on 18.04.x, not on 20.04.1 - I have included a screenshot of how it shows.
(Please note it doesn't work on a fresh install of 20.04 or an upgraded 18.04 to 20.04 either)

[image]

Comment: figured it out yet?